# regression with continuous and categorial data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am still beginner in machine learning field. Suppose there is simple data like this:

```
+--------+--------+-----------------+
| Age    | Gender | Mortality Rates |
+--------+--------+-----------------+
|      0 | Male   | 0.01            |
|     30 | Female | 0.2             |
|     80 | Male   | 30              |
+--------+--------+-----------------+
```

To get Mortality rate by age, we can use regression and by gender we use classification. What is common method to combine them in one machine learning algorithm to produce output prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two things:

1. input data types

   You have categorial (gender) and discrete numerical features (age).
2. Learning task

   Classification: prediction of a categorial feature. Regression: prediction of a numerical feature.

Decision trees for example work best with categorial input for classification. SVMs do classification on numerical data. SVR is the regression variant of SVMs.

I have updated your question title.

An approach you should try is to encode your category as binary attributes (e.g. male: 1, female 0), then do regular regression.